# Need some t-sql clarification

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, scope-identity

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512661/why-am-i-getting-invalidcastexception-when-casting-object-to-integer), in t-sql

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

returns a BIGINT, I did the following to get it to return an INT:

```
DECLARE @X INT

INSERT ...

SELECT @X = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- if i don't include the line below, it will return a BIGINT

SELECT @X
```

Why does it return a BIGINT unless I do SELECT @X at the end?

p.s. turns out

```
SELECT @X = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

doesn't return anything, it just sets @x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

returns a BIGINT as you have seen

```
SELECT @X = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

returns BIGINT and casts it into INT variable @X

So you are returning BIGINT SCOPE_IDENTITY and also concurrently casting it to INT and setting that result to @X.

Returning @X returns the INT result.

[Just some interesting reading on the subject.](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/differences_between_set_and_select.htm)

> SQL Server 7.0 Books Online also
>   stated: "It is recommended that SET
>   @local_variable be used for variable
>   assignment rather than SELECT
>   @local_variable."

Comment: i have a problem with "returns BIGINT and casts it into INT variable @X" ... it doesn't seem to do this, it returns a bigint unless i explicitly do select @x

Comment: I read it again, and it what I said is a little ambiguous, hopefully I clarified it.

Comment: so, basically select @x = scope_identity() is the same as select scope_identity() set @x = scope_identity() ?

Comment: I've been testing to verify my answer.  On sql server 2005 the line SELECT @X = SCOPE_IDENTITY() actually returns nothing in a query.  I have not tried it in a stored procedure yet, but I would expect the same results there.

Comment: In spite of what SQL Server 7.0 Books Online says, SELECT @x = has two advantages: (1) you can assign multiple variables in one statement, and (2) when you do so, it is marginally faster than multiple independent SETs.  (See Alexander's article here: http://is.gd/4o8Iw)

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
  SELECT @X = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

is an assignment statement. As in most programming languages, an assignment statement is executed by first evaluating the right hand side. In this case the right hand side evaluates to a bigint. When the value of @X gets the resulting bigint, there is an implicit type conversion, because @X is a different type (int) than the value it's receiving.

SQL is a typed language, and the type of an expression (such as SCOPE_IDENTITY() here) depends on the expression, not on what happens to the expression's value after evaluation.

Analogy:

```
DECLARE @i INT;
SET @i = 3.2 + 0.2;
```

You wouldn't suggest that 3.2 + 0.2 is an integer, would you? It's 3.4, a decimal. Only because of the assignment is there an implicit conversion to INT.

There's no magic in most programming languages.